# Python // Pandas - only select the rows that have certain conditions in a given column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
df:

    Estado:                        Telefone 
0        SP  (11) 2162-0660 / (11) 2162-0639
1        RJ                   (11) 3144-4000
2        SC                   (62) 3878-8150
3        RS                   (11) 4593-7403
4        PR  (19) 3313-5680 / (19) 3313-6000
5        PE                   (81) 3316-0586
6        GO                   (19) 3423-8000
...
[379 rows x 2 columns]
```

I want to put in a new dataframe only the items that are from the state (`'Estado:'`) of SP, RJ, RS or PR.

I tried the line below:

```
lista=lista.loc[lista['Estado:'] == ('RJ' or 'SP' or 'PR' or 'RS')]
```

However it is bringing me a very limited list and all the items have `Estado:` are `RJ`.

```
lista: 

    Estado:                        Telefone 
16       RJ                   (31) 3263-9664
47       RJ                   (21) 3575-0600
48       RJ                   (21) 3221-0000
60       RJ                   (11) 2118-9500
69       RJ  (21) 2677-1077 / (21) 2252-1989
82       RJ                   (21) 3224-8091
83       RJ                              NaN
105      RJ  (24) 2233-1877 / (24) 2233-1874
140      RJ                   (31) 3660-9100
143      RJ                   (21) 2277-2000
175      RJ                   (21) 3435-1002
216      RJ                   (21) 9428-1902
218      RJ  (21) 2142-1482 / (21) 2142-1480
235      RJ                   (11) 3468-2098
274      RJ                              NaN
315      RJ                   (21) 2676-9196
[16 rows x 2 columns]
```

Can someone help?

EDIT:

I try `isin`, but get error:

> TypeError: isin() takes 2 positional arguments but 5 were given

Comment: Use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) - `lista=lista[lista['Estado:'].isin(['RJ' , 'SP' , 'PR' , 'RS'])]`

Comment: I checked a few posts related to isin before and actually tried it, however they didn't explain how to use it with multiple items (I was getting some error like 'isin only accepts two arguments you have four'. With your tip I noticed I should use those brackets and it worked. Tks!

Comment: Super, gald can help! Good luck!

Comment: You are correct @jezrael, however it is not super clear and could make a beginner like me get confused. I think its valid to keep this one in case someone like me comes to have this doubt.

Comment: I add answer, but first add your error to question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need add `[]` to [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html), because parameter `values` is:

> **values** : *set* or *list-like*
>
> The sequence of values to test. Passing in a single string will raise a TypeError. Instead, turn a single string into a list of one element.

```
lista=lista[lista['Estado:'].isin(['RJ' , 'SP' , 'PR' , 'RS'])]
print (lista)
  Estado:                         Telefone
0      SP  (11) 2162-0660 / (11) 2162-0639
1      RJ                   (11) 3144-4000
3      RS                   (11) 4593-7403
4      PR  (19) 3313-5680 / (19) 3313-6000
```

---

```
lista=lista[lista['Estado:'].isin('RJ' , 'SP' , 'PR' , 'RS')]
print (lista)
```

> TypeError: isin() takes 2 positional arguments but 5 were given